# git push error:remote: error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Tags: git

```
on server:  
    /git             755 git:git  
    /git/gitdemo.git 755 git:git  

on local(mac mini):  
    /opt/webroot                775 nobody:nobody  
    /opt/webroot/gitdemo        777 user:nobody
    /opt/webroot/gitdemo/.git/* 777 user:nobody

>git clone git@server:/git/gitdemo.git  gitdemo
```

i use ssh to login without password.
it's ok with:

```
>git pull origin master
```

but it's error with:

```
>git push origin master
```

the full error info:

```
>git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 233 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
remote:
remote: error: unable to update .git/info/refs+
remote: error: cannot open .git/objects/info/packs+
To git@***/git/gitdemo.git
   9fef5a8..f531910  master -> master
```

but it pushed successfully,although it reported permission error.

chmod,chown doesn't work.
Need help,pls.

Comment: You don't have write permission on the repository on the server. Check with the server admin.

Comment: but it pushed successfully,what would be the problem on server?

Comment: Pushing to the server means you have ssh access to the server. But you may not have permission to write to the git repository. Ask the server admin to verify that you do. Have you pushed to this repository before?

Comment: i am the server admin, and the repo is mine. i tried to build my repo and stuck in thie error.

Comment: the error is:remote: error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD, and this flie only in local. i'm not sure the problem is on server. i chmod 777 on server still won't work.

Comment: It's on the server because it starts with the word `remote`

Answer (score 0):

Check the following files:

```
/opt/webroot/gitdemo/.git/FETCH_HEAD
/opt/webroot/gitdemo/.git/info/refs
/opt/webroot/gitdemo/.git/objects/info/packs
```

They must be owned by 'user' on the mac mini, or at least, 'user' should have write permissions on these files (and the whole .git/ directory)

Comment: So the problem may be located on your git server, not locally

Comment: so what the problem would it be on server?any suggestion?

Comment: Not really. Error messages clearly states there is permissions issues. Check permissions on mentionned files, and verify they are coherent with the user that should connect to ssh.

Comment: the error is:remote: error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD, and this flie only in local. i'm not sure the problem is on server. i chmod 777 on server still won't work.